# How importing works. Why imported modules not inheriting other imported modules

Tags: python, module, import

I just "thought" I understood how importing and modules work but obviously I need more schooling.

Here is an example program (just a test case of somerthing I'm doing that is much bigger in scope and scale) and a module:

quick.py

```
import gtk
from quick_window import *

w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

quick_window.py

```
w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
l=gtk.Label('Hello')
w.add(l)
```

running I get

```
$ python quick.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 2, in <module>
    from quick_window import *
  File "/home/woodnt/Dropbox/python/weather_project/plugins/quick_window.py", line 3, in <module>
    w = gtk.Window()
NameError: name 'gtk' is not defined
```

To get it to work, I have to also import (er, reimport) gtk in the module like so:

```
import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
l=gtk.Label('Hello')
w.add(l)
```

Why should I have to import gtk more than once? Does that mean that I have 2 "gtk's" in memory?

Do I have to import everything within each module that I need within that module?

I know each module has it's own namespace, but I thought it also inherited the "globals" including imported module from the calling program.

I had been under the impression the from module import * is like cutting and pasting the code right into that location. Is there another way to do that?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Narnie

Comment: At the very least because you are not supposed to write modules under the assumption that the importing module also imported a specific module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The details of importing get very complicated, but conceptually it is very simple.

When you write:

```
import some_module
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
some_module = import_module("some_module")
```

where import_module is kind of like:

```
def import_module(modname):
    if modname in sys.modules:
        module = sys.modules[modname]
    else:
        filename = find_file_for_module(modname)
        python_code = open(filename).read()
        module = create_module_from_code(python_code)
        sys.modules[modname] = module
    return module
```

Two things to note here: the assignment of some_module is specific: an import statement really does nothing in the current module except assign a module object to the name you specify.  That's why you don't automatically get the names from the imported module, and why it isn't like copying the imported code into the current module.

Also, in the import_module pseudo-function, if the name has already been imported somewhere, it will be in the global list of all modules (sys.modules), and so will simply be reused.  The file won't be opened again, it won't be executed again, the globals in that modules won't get new values again, and so on.  Importing the same module into many places is not wasteful or extra work, it is very fast.

Comment: This peak "under the hood" helps me understand better what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

import is required to bring the contents of the py file into the namespace of that module - if you don't import, the names in it cannot be referenced.

Some more info: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

> When Python imports a module, it first
>   checks the module registry
>   (sys.modules) to see if the module is
>   already imported. If that’s the case,
>   Python uses the existing module object
>   as is.

Comment: Take particular note that no matter how many times you import the module, the outer-scope code in the imported module runs only once (barring unload & reload, of course). OP will not have 2 'gtk's in memory. The effect of subsequent imports is only to bring things into the local namespace.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. It seems a lot of "extra" work and a bit of a waste to do this, but if that is the way it is, that is the way it is. Thank for the link. I just started reading it and I think it is exactly what I need to think better in python.